# Finding range of $||x| - |y||$ for the given conditions.

Tags: functions

> If $ z = x + iy$ and $ x^2 + y^2 = 16 $ , then the range of $||x|-|y||$ is...?

This is what I've tried yet:

Suppose $x = a\cos \theta$ and $y = b\sin \theta$,  then we've :

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 = 16 \implies & a^2\cos^2 \theta + b^2\sin^2 \theta= 16 \\
\implies & a^2 + \sin^2 \theta(b^2 - a^2) = 16 \\
\implies & \sin^2 \theta = \cfrac{16 - a^2}{b^2 - a^2} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Not sure from where to go on from here. Putting the same values in $ z = x+iy$ and then squaring both sides doesn't give anything fruitful too.

Comment: What information do you get from $z=x+iy$? I mean, the question is equivalent to $x, y /in /mathbb{R},... $?

Comment: Well, if I can assume $ z = e^{i \theta} $ then it would be fair enough. So, I guess, that's what I got from $ z = x + iy$.... that is I can write $x = a \cos \theta$ and $ y = b\sin \theta$ .

Comment: Although, what I think is.. it would have been easier if I could assume $x = a\cos \theta$ and $ y = a\sin \theta$ .. this would have concluded that $a = \pm 4 $ . But, what I'm wondering is, will it be fair enough to assume this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:-**

Put $x=4\sin\theta$ and $y=4\cos \theta$.

**Solution**

> Then, $$||x|-|y||=4||\sin\theta|-|\cos \theta||$$Now, $$0\le|\sin\theta|\le 1$$and, $$-1\le-|\cos\theta|\le0$$which gives, $$||\sin\theta|-|\cos \theta||\le1\implies 4||\sin\theta|-|\cos \theta||\le4$$

Comment: Yep! That's what I concluded but just by logic. May I know how you got to that part? $ x = 4\sin \theta$ and $ y = 4\cos \theta$ ...

Comment: That is easy. Write $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ by Euler's formula.

Comment: Oh, okay! That's cool. I was just forgetting that $|z|$ part in Euler's form.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. :)

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: Glad that my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If $x, y \in \mathbb{R} $, then you find that the range is $[0,4]$. In fact, just because $||x|-|y|| \geq 0$ and you can easily find $x, y$ such that $x=y \wedge x^2+y^2=16$. The other bound is given by this argument: you can assume $x, y \geq 0$, in fact if they are both $\leq 0$ you get the same results multiplying by $-1$, and if $x\geq 0 \wedge y<0$ than you apply the same argument.
So, since they are both $\geq 0$, assuming $x\leq y$, you get $y \leq 4$, in other cases $x^2+y^2 \geq y^2 > 16$. So $||y|-|x|| \leq 4$.

Comment: I saw a different bound in the other answer. Is my argument wrong? Can I get an example of x, y in the hypothesis such that ||x|-|y||>4?

Comment: See the edited proof. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yeah that seems ok for me!

Answer (score 1):

Taking $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=a\sin\theta$ won't be helpful because all you will be doing is introducing two more variables a and b making the solution more messy.. 
So in such cases think about a case to simplify either RHS or LHS..
Here this can be done by assuming $x=4\sin\theta$ and $y=4\cos\theta$

In most of these questions, keeping the objective of question in mind I'd helpful...

Comment: That's wise advice! Thanks a lot for taking time to help me out.